# Unable to increase performance of the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query as below which is taking about 10 mins to runs, which I have to optimize. I tried my bit but I am unable to increase its performance. Any help is really appreciated

```
SELECT  ISNULL(OX.intStore, DX.intStore) AS sStore
    ,   OX.dtmCreatedDate
    ,   ISNULL(OX.strBarcode, ISNULL(DX.strClientText, DX.FirstBarCode)) AS sBarcode
    ,   ISNULL(OX.strAreaName, DX.strAreaName) AS sArea
    ,   ISNULL(OX.strDesc, 'N/F') AS sDesc
    ,   ISNULL(OX.czBrand, 'N/F') AS sBrand
    ,   ISNULL(OX.decCost, 0) AS nCost
    ,   ISNULL(DX.SumQty, 0) AS nHT_Unit
    ,   ISNULL(OX.fltQty, 0) AS nOH_Unit
    ,   (ISNULL(DX.SumQty, 0) * ISNULL(OX.decCost, 0)) AS nEXTCost
    ,   (ISNULL(OX.fltQty, 0) * ISNULL(OX.decCost, 0)) AS nOH_EXTCost
    ,   (ISNULL(DX.SumQty, 0) - ISNULL(OX.fltQty, 0)) AS nVarUnit
    ,   (ISNULL(DX.SumQty, 0) - ISNULL(OX.fltQty, 0)) * ISNULL(OX.decCost, 0) AS nVarCost
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT OH.intStore
                ,   OH.strBarcode
                ,   SA.intAreaGrp
                ,   OH.strDesc
                ,   OH.czBrand
                ,   OH.decCost
                ,   AG.strAreaName
                ,   OH.fltQty
                ,   OH.dtmCreatedDate
    FROM tblOnHand AS OH
    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblStickerAreas AS SA ON (OH.intArea = SA.intAreaNo)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblAreaGrp AS AG ON (SA.intAreaGrp = AG.intAreaGrp)
) AS OX
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT  DT.intStore
        ,   DT.strClientText
        ,   SA.intAreaGrp
        ,   AG.strAreaName
        ,   SUM(DT.fltQty) SumQty
        ,   MIN(DT.strBarCode) FirstBarCode
    FROM dbo.tblDetail AS DT
    JOIN dbo.tblSticker AS SK ON (DT.intStore = SK.intStore 
        AND DT.intStickerNo = SK.intStickerNo 
        AND DT.dtmstickerdate = SK.dtmstickerdate 
        AND SK.strrescansw = 'N')
    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblStickerAreas AS SA ON (SK.intAreaNo = SA.intAreaNo)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblAreaGrp AS AG ON (SA.intAreaGrp = AG.intAreaGrp)
    --WHERE strrescansw = 'N'
    GROUP BY
            DT.intStore
        ,   DT.strClientText
        ,   SA.intAreaGrp
        ,   AG.strAreaName
) AS DX ON OX.intStore = DX.intStore AND OX.strBarcode = DX.strClientText
```

The table and indexes are

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblAreaGrp](
    [intAreaGrp] [int] NULL,
    [strAreaName] [char](20) NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblAreaGrp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDetail](
    [intStore] [int] NOT NULL,
    [intStickerNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dtmStickerDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [intLineNum] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [strBarcode] [char](14) NULL,
    [intBarcodeLength] [tinyint] NULL,
    [intBarcodeType] [tinyint] NULL,
    [strBarcodeEntrySW] [char](1) NULL,
    [strBarcodeSW] [char](1) NULL,
    [fltQty] [float] NULL,
    [fltPrice] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
    [strPriceSW] [char](1) NULL,
    [strQtySW] [char](1) NULL,
    [strAddSW] [char](1) NULL,
    [strDeleteSW] [char](1) NULL,
    [strPTCCode1] [char](1) NULL,
    [strPTCCode2] [char](1) NULL,
    [strPTCCode3] [char](1) NULL,
    [strPTCCode4] [char](1) NULL,
    [strPTCCode5] [char](1) NULL,
    [strInternalUseOnly] [char](1) NULL,
    [strMiscText] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [strClientText] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [strSKU] [char](14) NULL,
    [intSKULength] [tinyint] NULL,
    [intSKUType] [tinyint] NULL,
    [fltOldQty] [float] NULL,
    [blnVerifyNOF] [bit] NULL,
    [blnVerifyTS] [bit] NULL,
    [blnNOF] [bit] NULL,
    [EnteredValue] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [AcceptedValue] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [MasterFileValue] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [QuantityEntered] [int] NULL,
    [intSku] [int] NULL,
    [intUpc] [bigint] NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SerialNumber] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [MFQuantity] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [InvoiceFlag] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [CancelFlag] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblDetail] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [intStore] ASC,
    [intStickerNo] ASC,
    [dtmStickerDate] ASC,
    [intLineNum] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblOnHand](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [intStore] [int] NULL,
    [intArea] [int] NOT NULL,
    [strBarcode] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [strDesc] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [fltQty] [float] NOT NULL,
    [decCost] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
    [czLocation] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [czLocCode] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [czPartNum] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [czPartDesc] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [czBrand] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [czCategory] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [czSEB] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [czLastRec] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [czWAC] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [czExtWAC] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [dtmCreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSticker](
    [intStore] [int] NOT NULL,
    [intStickerNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dtmStickerDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [strRescanSW] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [intCorrectionID] [int] NULL,
    [intSessionNo] [int] NULL,
    [strCorrectionStatus] [char](1) NULL,
    [strEmptyStatus] [char](1) NULL,
    [intLastLineNo] [smallint] NULL,
    [fltTotalUnits] [float] NULL,
    [fltTotalValue] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
    [strDeductionSW] [char](1) NULL,
    [intDeviceNo] [int] NULL,
    [intAreaNo] [int] NULL,
    [dtmAreaStartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [dtmTeamStartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [dtmTeamPrintedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [strTeamNo] [char](9) NULL,
    [strSessionNo] [char](3) NULL,
    [strTeamTrainingSW] [char](1) NULL,
    [dtmFixtureStartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [dtmFixtureEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [strFixtureEcsCode] [char](1) NULL,
    [strHHRecordTypeSW] [char](1) NULL,
    [strFixtureTrainingSW] [char](1) NULL,
    [strEmptyFixtureSW] [char](1) NULL,
    [strCorrectionStatus2] [char](1) NULL,
    [strMiscText] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [strClientMisc1] [char](1) NULL,
    [strClientMisc2] [char](1) NULL,
    [intClientMisc1] [int] NULL,
    [intClientMisc2] [int] NULL,
    [fltClientMisc1] [float] NULL,
    [fltClientMisc2] [float] NULL,
    [strClientText] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [blnPieceCount] [bit] NULL,
    [bitOverrideMode] [bit] NULL,
    [blnAuditMode] [bit] NULL,
    [AutoPrint] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AutoPrintDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblSticker] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [intStore] ASC,
    [intStickerNo] ASC,
    [dtmStickerDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblStickerAreas](
    [intAreaFlag] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [intAreaNo] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [strAreaName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [blnAllAreas] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [intAreaGrp] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_StoreClientText] ON [dbo].[tblDetail]
(
    [intStore] ASC,
    [strClientText] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_CreatedDate] ON [dbo].[tblOnHand]
(
    [dtmCreatedDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_intArea] ON [dbo].[tblOnHand]
(
    [intArea] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [intStore],
    [strBarcode],
    [strDesc],
    [fltQty],
    [decCost],
    [czBrand],
    [dtmCreatedDate]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_StoreAreaBar] ON [dbo].[tblOnHand]
(
    [intStore] ASC,
    [intArea] ASC,
    [strBarcode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_tblSticker_204_2025058250__K4_K1_K2_K3_K14] ON [dbo].[tblSticker]
(
    [strRescanSW] ASC,
    [intStore] ASC,
    [intStickerNo] ASC,
    [dtmStickerDate] ASC,
    [intAreaNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_intAreaNo] ON [dbo].[tblStickerAreas]
(
    [intAreaNo] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [strAreaName]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Very hard to help with just the SQL. Please provide more details like the underlying table structures, indexes, data volume, server resources, etc.

Comment: Try sqlfiddle ? Would be easier for everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very quick test you could do is modify it to use temp tables. This may or may not have much impact, but it's a quick test to try.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OH.intStore
            ,   OH.strBarcode
            ,   SA.intAreaGrp
            ,   OH.strDesc
            ,   OH.czBrand
            ,   OH.decCost
            ,   AG.strAreaName
            ,   OH.fltQty
            ,   OH.dtmCreatedDate
INTO #TEMP_OX
FROM tblOnHand AS OH
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblStickerAreas AS SA ON (OH.intArea = SA.intAreaNo)
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblAreaGrp AS AG ON (SA.intAreaGrp = AG.intAreaGrp)

SELECT  DT.intStore
    ,   DT.strClientText
    ,   SA.intAreaGrp
    ,   AG.strAreaName
    ,   SUM(DT.fltQty) SumQty
    ,   MIN(DT.strBarCode) FirstBarCode
INTO #TEMP_DX
FROM dbo.tblDetail AS DT
JOIN dbo.tblSticker AS SK ON (DT.intStore = SK.intStore 
    AND DT.intStickerNo = SK.intStickerNo 
    AND DT.dtmstickerdate = SK.dtmstickerdate 
    AND SK.strrescansw = 'N')
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblStickerAreas AS SA ON (SK.intAreaNo = SA.intAreaNo)
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblAreaGrp AS AG ON (SA.intAreaGrp = AG.intAreaGrp)
--WHERE strrescansw = 'N'
GROUP BY
        DT.intStore
    ,   DT.strClientText
    ,   SA.intAreaGrp
    ,   AG.strAreaName

SELECT  ISNULL(OX.intStore, DX.intStore) AS sStore
    ,   OX.dtmCreatedDate
    ,   ISNULL(OX.strBarcode, ISNULL(DX.strClientText, DX.FirstBarCode)) AS sBarcode
    ,   ISNULL(OX.strAreaName, DX.strAreaName) AS sArea
    ,   ISNULL(OX.strDesc, 'N/F') AS sDesc
    ,   ISNULL(OX.czBrand, 'N/F') AS sBrand
    ,   ISNULL(OX.decCost, 0) AS nCost
    ,   ISNULL(DX.SumQty, 0) AS nHT_Unit
    ,   ISNULL(OX.fltQty, 0) AS nOH_Unit
    ,   (ISNULL(DX.SumQty, 0) * ISNULL(OX.decCost, 0)) AS nEXTCost
    ,   (ISNULL(OX.fltQty, 0) * ISNULL(OX.decCost, 0)) AS nOH_EXTCost
    ,   (ISNULL(DX.SumQty, 0) - ISNULL(OX.fltQty, 0)) AS nVarUnit
    ,   (ISNULL(DX.SumQty, 0) - ISNULL(OX.fltQty, 0)) * ISNULL(OX.decCost, 0) AS nVarCost
FROM #TEMP_OX
FULL OUTER JOIN #TEMP_DX 
     ON OX.intStore = DX.intStore AND OX.strBarcode = DX.strClientText
```

Other than that, without more details of schema and indexes it's difficult to tune this SQL. If you can run the query and check the execution plan you'll be able to see where the delays are coming from.